# Создание запроса для MS SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Необходимо создать запрос по следующему описанию:
Не совсем понимаю, как. Написано сложным языком. Требуют использовать COUNT? 
Со второй частью пытался в ISNULL. Но смысл, если в таблицах поля "Name" и "ProductCategoryID" не могут принимать значение NULL. KEKW.
Что я пытался:

```
'''use AdventureWorks2012
Select name,  ProductID
From Production.Product
Where ProductSubcategoryID = '2'
SELECT 
ISNULL (ProductCategoryID, '5') as ID,
ISNULL (Name, ' Не определено') as name
FROM Production.ProductSubcategory'''
```

"Отобрать из таблицы продуктов(Product) количество продуктов(ProductID) в той же категории, что и этот продукт. 
Так же из таблицы категорий(ProductCategory) отобразить код категории (ProductCategoryID, если код равен NULL то заменить его на '5') 
и наименование категории(Name, если наименование категории равно NULL, то заменить на 'No category'). 
Для связи таблицы продуктов(Product) и таблицы категорий(ProductCategory) необходимо использовать таблицу связей - ProductSubCategory"
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]